# GoLang set library (golang-set) not compiling

Tags: go, set

I was using this set library [golang-set](https://github.com/deckarep/golang-set). I get the following error when trying to create a set:

```
invalid operation: cannot index mapset.NewSet (value of type func(s ...interface{}) mapset.Set)
```

Here is the full code

```
package main

import (
    mapset "github.com/deckarep/golang-set"
)

func main() {
    mySet := mapset.NewSet[string]()

}
```

I'm using go version 1.18.2 on Ubuntu, the code is exactly how it appears on the documentation.

Comment: I think the documentation is wrong, the import should be `mapset "github.com/deckarep/golang-set/v2"`

Comment: Thanks, this works after changing the version in go.mod to 2.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joachim Isaksson noted, it should be imported as

```
import (
    mapset "github.com/deckarep/golang-set/v2"
)
```

also in go.mod the version should be 2xx, as of now it is at 2.1.0

```
require github.com/deckarep/golang-set/v2 v2.1.0
```